# Encontrar duplicados en MySQL

Tags: mysql, eliminar-duplicados

Tengo una tabla de MySQL con las siguientes columnas:

```
id              PrimaryKey Autoincrementable
id_actor        INT Not Null
id_escenario    INT Not Null
id_obra         INT Not Null
```

Necesito encontrar los registros duplicados por los ters campos de tipo INT, es decir los registros que tengan los mismos valores de id_actor, id_escenario e id_obra.

He visto varias consultas para detectar duplicados en una sola columna, pero yo necesito detectar los duplicados en el conjunto de las tres columnas. Es decir, si dos registros tienen el mismo valor de id_actor e id_escenario, pero distinto valor en id_obra, esos no son duplicados.

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que buscas, simplemente podes agrupar por los 3 campos que queres que sean iguales, y agregar un count del otro. para los casos en los cuales count sea mayor a 1, vas a tener tus duplicados.

```
select id_actor,id_escenario,id_obra, count(id)
from tabla
group by id_actor,id_escenario,id_obra
having count(id) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar las funciones `GROUP BY` y `HAVING` para obtener un resultado como el que muestro a continuación...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo en cuenta este esquema...

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE demo (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_actor INT NOT NULL,
    id_escenario INT NOT NULL,
    id_obra INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
-- data
INSERT INTO demo
    (id_actor, id_escenario, id_obra)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, 2, 1),
    (1, 1, 2),
    (2, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 1),
    (3, 1, 1)
;
```

Y esta consulta...

```
SELECT * 
FROM demo
GROUP BY id_actor, id_escenario, id_obra
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```