# Obtener (Ver) registros duplicados en MySQL (Una sola columna)

Tags: mysql

He estado investigando como encontrar duplicados de un registro en una base de datos y en eso encuentro esta respuesta:

[Encontrar duplicados en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/556151/encontrar-duplicados-en-mysql/556155#556155): esta respuesta tiene como objetivo encontrar duplicados en ***multiples*** columnas de la misma tabla, mientras yo busco ducplicados en ***una*** sola columna.

Pero no logro mi objetivo. lo que intengo es visualizar los N record duplicados.

***Estructura y datos de ejemplo:***

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `prueba`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba` (
  `id` bigint(21) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Id de la tabla',
  `name` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'nombre',
  `prod_ft` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'codigo',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

INSERT INTO `prueba` VALUES 
(1, 'Pepe Pelotas 1', 'FT202201001'),
(2, 'Pepe Pelotas 2', 'FT202201001'),
(3, 'Pepe Pelotas 3', 'FT202201003'),
(4, 'Pepe Pelotas 4', 'FT202201004'),
(5, 'Pepe Pelotas 5', 'Actualizar');
```

***Query:***

```
SELECT * FROM prueba WHERE `prod_ft` != 'Actualizar' GROUP BY `prod_ft` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

***Resultado:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***[Ejemplo en sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bc881/1)***

***Resultado esperado:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: este problema es lo que describo [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359) al no agregar la informacion que falta en el select.. lo que ves, es cualquier cosa...

Comment: @gbianchi gracias, pero no entiendo como eso soluciona mi ejemplo/escenario, XD.

Comment: en teoria quiero obtener duplicados sin agruparlos ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero deberías ver que `pord_ft` se encuentra repetido, la forma mas consistente con el estándar SQL y que Mysql se niega a respetar es así:

```
SELECT prod_ft 
       FROM prueba 
       WHERE `prod_ft` != 'Actualizar' 
       GROUP BY `prod_ft` 
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Si ya tienes los `prod_ft` simplemente filtra las filas que coincidan con estos:

```
SELECT *
       FROM prueba 
       WHERE prod_ft IN (SELECT prod_ft 
                                FROM prueba 
                                WHERE `prod_ft` != 'Actualizar' 
                                GROUP BY `prod_ft` 
                                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       )
```

Con `inner join`:

```
SELECT *
       FROM prueba p1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT prod_ft 
                                FROM prueba 
                                WHERE `prod_ft` != 'Actualizar' 
                                GROUP BY `prod_ft` 
                                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                   ) p2
                   ON p1.prod_ft = p2.prod_ft
```

Comment: acabo de escribir exactamente lo mismo en el chat :p

Comment: Listo ahora si es que jamas me imagine que tenia que anidar la consulta... como se expresa esto con inner join???

Comment: Las "subconsultas" son conceptualmente una tabla más, ahí te agregué la forma mediante un `join`.